# link shortner with Hebrew characters

Tags: xml, vba, vb6

I'm using the following function for successfully shortening long links. My issue is that it fails to render properly Hebrew characters used in URL variables. It looks that I should add something to the encoding function but I'm not familiar with encoding matters

```
Function GetShortURL(url As String, index As Integer) As String

url = URLEncode(url)
Dim xml As Object
Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")

Select Case index
 Case 0 ' tinyURL
      xml.Open "POST", "http://tinyurlcom/api-create.php?url=" & url, False
      xml.Send



      End Select

 GetShortURL = xml.ResponseText

  End Function

 Public Function URLEncode( _
 StringVal As String, _
 Optional SpaceAsPlus As Boolean = False _
 ) As String

    Dim StringLen As Long: StringLen = Len(StringVal)

 If StringLen > 0 Then
 ReDim result(StringLen) As String
 Dim i As Long, CharCode As Integer
 Dim Char As String, Space As String

 If SpaceAsPlus Then Space = "+" Else Space = "%20"

 For i = 1 To StringLen
      Char = Mid$(StringVal, i, 1)
      CharCode = Asc(Char)
      Select Case CharCode
           Case 97 To 122, 65 To 90, 48 To 57, 45, 46, 95, 126, 128
                result(i) = Char
           Case 32
                result(i) = Space
           Case 0 To 15
                result(i) = "%0" & Hex(CharCode)
           Case Else
                result(i) = "%" & Hex(CharCode)
      End Select
 Next i
 URLEncode = Join(result, "")

 End If
 End Function
```

Comment: Hebrew characters aren't contained in the ASCII set of characters. Which means you don't want to use ASC(), you want to use ASCW() function. More info: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2010/11/19/unicode-and-vbas-chrw-and-ascw-functions/

Comment: For HTML there are special characters.  See wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references.  In net library use following for encoding and decoding : System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode("string") and  
                System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("string")